# Discrepancy between openssl verify and s_client command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openssl, x509certificate

Running on Ubuntu 14.04 with OpenSSL 1.0.1l:

```
 openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs -showcerts -connect www.google.com:443
```

Returns:

```
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

However, running:

```
openssl verify -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ google_chain.pem
```

where google_chain.pem is the output of the s_client command above, returns:

```
google_chain.pem: C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google Inc, CN = google.com
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Can someone explain this discrepancy? It seems to me that the openssl verify command is just ignoring the -CApath parameter.

Comment: Maybe you should [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`openssl verify` doesn't expect the certificate to contain its chain. Chain needs to be passed with `-untrusted` argument. You can pass the same file there, trust is still determined by finding a trusted root in `-CAfile/-CApath`.

```
openssl verify -CApath /etc/ssl/certs -untrusted google_chain.pem google_chain.pem
```